# Is there a Bluetooth device that one can connect a wired headset

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I'm trying to achieve two goals.

1. Use my headset without plugging it into my phone
2. configure smart lock with the bluetooth so my cell phone stays unlocked while in my home office.

Currently I have a Sennheiser SD Pro 2 with an adapter cable plugged into the "phone" port on the base station that converts to a 3.5mm TRRS connector that I plug into my Galaxy S10.  This allows me to use the Sennheiser headset for phone calls on my phone.

I'm looking for a Bluetooth device that I can connect to the TRRS jack and then pair with my phone so that I can use the Sennheiser headset in the same way that I do now. The Bluetooth device and phone would remain on my desk, but I would be able to move around my house with the headset.

All of the products I've found are for transmit *OR* receive, or have a built in mic and only *send* audio.

Can anyone provide a link to a product that I can currently buy or detailed instructions on how I might combine a few parts?

I don't mind soldering.